# How do they imprement this kind of button in attached picture of iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

[image: multiple button with next to another]

Hello everyone,
I need help on creating a button like in the above picture.
They are multiple buttons that are used to switch to another view and the next button to show a hidden button.

I 'd like to know which UI Control to use.
Whichever free ready-to-use control or code example is preferred.

Thank you very much.

I did what Mayur Joshi's suggestion but don't understand why I can't scroll buttons in scrollview and there's no text on buttons.

This is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];




    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500.0f, 50.0f)];
    [self.view addSubview: scrollView];

    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Button1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0F, 0.0F, 100.0F, 50.0F)];
    [scrollView addSubview:button1];
    [button1 release];


    UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button2 setTitle:@"Button2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(100.0F, 0.0F, 100.0F, 50.0F)];
    [scrollView addSubview:button2];

    [button2 release];


    UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button3 setTitle:@"Button3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button3 setFrame:CGRectMake(200.0F, 0.0F, 100.0F, 50.0F)];
    [scrollView addSubview:button3];

    [button3 release];

    UIButton *button4 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button4 setTitle:@"Button4" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button4 setFrame:CGRectMake(300.0F, 0.0F, 100.0F, 50.0F)];
    [scrollView addSubview:button4];

    [button4 release];

    UIButton *button5 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button5 setTitle:@"Button5" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button5 setFrame:CGRectMake(400.0F, 0.0F, 100.0F, 50.0F)];
    [scrollView addSubview:button5];

    [button5 release];


}
```

[you can download source code here](http://codesanook.com/code/buttoninscrollview.zip)

This is app screen shot.
[image: button in scrollview screen shot]

Comment: these are just buttons added into the UIScrollview

Comment: @Mayur Joshi I follow your suggestion but I have some problem. So I add example code in main question post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the release methods from the buttons and you are good to go.

Actually, when you declare the buttons with

```
 UIButton* btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

it is already in auto-release mode as its a class method and not a static method. So you dont need to write

```
 [btn1 release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this.

https://github.com/judges/RXCustomTabBar

I have used and its so easy to integrate

You can also try this although i have not tried:

https://github.com/aalittle/ALCustomTabBarController

Answer (score 1):

From the implementation perspective, the most likely candidate seems to be a customized UISegmentedControl, as only one out of Fixtures, League Tables or Latest Score can be active at a time.

However, if the UISegmentedControl cannot be customized to that extent, this can simply be implemented with a series of UIButtons placed beside each other. When the rightmost arrow button is tapped, you can shift the buttons towards the left, and animate this transition.

HTH,

Akshay